# Android camera locks/crashes if used in Service with screen off

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

If I try to use a camera in a service with the screen off, the camera eventually becomes locked and unusable, the phone will reboot, or the camera driver will segfault (mm-camera). The only way to recover from the camera locking or mm-camera segfaulting is to reboot the device. It seems that the camera is tied directly to the screen in such a way if the screen is not on the camera doesn't work properly. If the phone is plugged into my computer and Android Debugging is running, then the camera does not experience the same issue. I have taken several variations of code and even tried using OpenCV’s  VideoCapture class which doesn't need a Surface and bypasses android.hardware.Camera completely, but the results are the same: if I run it with the screen on it works fine, if I run it with the screen off the camera will lock. Is this a bug with the camera code or was this purposely put in? Has anyone had an success with using the camera with the screen off?

I have tested this on the following devices
Motorola RAZR M
Samsung Galaxy S3 (Pre 4.3 update)*
Samsung Galaxy Note 3
Asus Transformer TF700
Nexus 7 Gen 2
LG G2

*Samsung Galaxy S3 with the 4.3 update doesn't exhibit the behavior.

Logcat of trying to use camera in bad state, note that errno 16 is EBUSY

```
I CameraHalWatchdog: Starting Watchdog Thread...
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_ops_close: my_obj=0x4151b008
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_ops_close: ref_count=0
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_proc_pipe: read_fd = 45, read_len = 52, expect_len = 52
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_proc_pipe: read_fd = 35, read_len = 52, expect_len = 52
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_proc_pipe: read_fd = 37, read_len = 52, expect_len = 52
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_proc_pipe: read_fd = 39, read_len = 52, expect_len = 52
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_proc_pipe: read_fd = 43, read_len = 52, expect_len = 52
I CameraHalWatchdog: Stopped Watchdog Thread...
I CameraHalWatchdog: Starting Watchdog Thread...
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_ops_open: g_cam_ctrl.cam_obj[camera_id] =0x4151b008, camera_id = 0
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_ops_open: poll_threads[0].data.used = 0
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_ops_open: poll_threads[1].data.used = 0
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_ops_open: poll_threads[2].data.used = 0
E mm-camera-hal: Errno:16
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_open:  ctrl_fd = -1
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_open:  opened, break out while loop
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_open:  after while loop
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_open: cannot open control fd of 'video0' Errno = 16
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_ops_close: my_obj=0x0
I CameraHalWatchdog: Stopped Watchdog Thread...
```

Logcat of a Motorola RAZR M mm-camera sefault

```
E mm-camera-hal: Run thread for ch_type = 0 
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_thread_add_ch : my_obj = 0x41960008, poll_cb = 0x41973d00, poll_cb->data.used = 1
E mm-camera: config_decide_vfe_outputs Current mode 0 Full size liveshot : Disabled
E mm-camera: config_decide_vfe_outputs: Ports Used 1, Op mode 64
E mm-camera: config_decide_vfe_outputs: Primary: 1920x1080, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 1, Path: 1
E mm-camera: config_decide_vfe_outputs: Secondary: 1920x1080, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 0, Type: 0, Path: 0
E mm-camera: config_set_op_mode_to_mctl_pp_video Camcorder configured in Low Power mode.
E mm-camera: config_MSM_V4L2_STREAM_ON Sending START CMD to VFE 
E mm-camera: config_CAMERA_START_VIDEO: received CAMERA_START_VIDEO!, ctrl->state = 0
E mm-camera: zoom_get_crop_factor: crop_factor = 4096
E mm-camera: sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_ov8820_video_hd.so: 31
E mm-camera: load_chromatix:37: for video hd chromatix_version=520
E mm-camera: sensor_load_chromatix:235: dlclose(libchromatix_handle) refcount 0
E mm-camera: config_MSG_ID_RESET_ACK Writing aec data to sensor: Real Gain 1.000000 Line count 1599 
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_proc_pipe: read_fd = 35, read_len = 52, expect_len = 52
E mm-camera-hal: mm_camera_poll_proc_pipe: poll_cb = 0x41973d00, poll_cb->data.used =1, Num fds after MM_CAMERA_PIPE_CMD_ADD_CH = 2
E mm-camera: vfe_config_mode: VideoCFg config 7ffffff
E mm-camera: vfe_operation_config: format 1
E mm-camera: vfe_operation_config:vfe_op_mode=4
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xc0debadd (code=1), thread 3400 (mm-qcamera-daem)
I DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'motorola/XT907_verizon/scorpion_mini:4.1.2/9.8.1Q-94/76:user/release-keys'
I DEBUG   : pid: 321, tid: 3400, name: mm-qcamera-daem  >>> /system/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon <<<
I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr c0debadd
I DEBUG   :     r0 41dab6b0  r1 deadbeef  r2 00000000  r3 c0debadd
I DEBUG   :     r4 413d595c  r5 00000000  r6 41d803e8  r7 413d595c
I DEBUG   :     r8 413d5908  r9 40186acc  sl 41d803e8  fp 00000008
I DEBUG   :     ip 80000000  sp 413d5810  lr 41d93be8  pc 401a3150  cpsr 80000030
I DEBUG   :     d0  c2dc0000001fa400  d1  000000f140a00000
I DEBUG   :     d2  ffffffcd43710000  d3  000000eac24c0000
I DEBUG   :     d4  ffffff92436a0000  d5  43180000c2dc0000
I DEBUG   :     d6  002f760000000005  d7  4147bb0000000000
I DEBUG   :     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d24 c020000000000000  d25 3fe0000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d26 4021000000000000  d27 4020000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d28 3fe0000000000000  d29 3fe0000000000000
I DEBUG   :     d30 0000000000000000  d31 bfe0000000000000
I DEBUG   :     scr 60000011
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : backtrace:
I DEBUG   :     #00  pc 0001b150  /system/lib/liboemcamera.so (mctl_proc_v4l2_request+1667)
I DEBUG   :     #01  pc 0001d39f  /system/lib/liboemcamera.so
I DEBUG   :     #02  pc 00012ef0  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
I DEBUG   :     #03  pc 00012648  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : stack:
I DEBUG   :          413d57d0  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d57d4  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d57d8  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d57dc  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d57e0  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d57e4  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d57e8  4019916b  /system/lib/liboemcamera.so (mmcamera_stacktrace+18)
I DEBUG   :          413d57ec  413d595c  
I DEBUG   :          413d57f0  0000000b  
I DEBUG   :          413d57f4  41d803e8  [heap]
I DEBUG   :          413d57f8  413d595c  
I DEBUG   :          413d57fc  413d5908  
I DEBUG   :          413d5800  40186acc  
I DEBUG   :          413d5804  41d803e8  [heap]
I DEBUG   :          413d5808  df0027ad  
I DEBUG   :          413d580c  00000000  
I DEBUG   :     #00  413d5810  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5814  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5818  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d581c  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5820  00000001  
I DEBUG   :          413d5824  413d595c  
I DEBUG   :          413d5828  40186acc  
I DEBUG   :          413d582c  401a3477  /system/lib/liboemcamera.so (mctl_proc_event_message+490)
I DEBUG   :          413d5830  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5834  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5838  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d583c  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5840  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5844  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5848  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d584c  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          ........  ........
I DEBUG   :     #01  413d58e0  00000008  
I DEBUG   :          413d58e4  0000000a  
I DEBUG   :          413d58e8  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d58ec  41d803e8  [heap]
I DEBUG   :          413d58f0  ffffffff  
I DEBUG   :          413d58f4  ffffffff  
I DEBUG   :          413d58f8  00000007  
I DEBUG   :          413d58fc  40186acc  
I DEBUG   :          413d5900  ffffffff  
I DEBUG   :          413d5904  ffffffff  
I DEBUG   :          413d5908  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d590c  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5910  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5914  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d5918  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          413d591c  00000000  
I DEBUG   :          ........  ........
I DEBUG   :     #02  413d6ef0  41dab590  [heap]
I DEBUG   :          413d6ef4  413d6f00  
I DEBUG   :          413d6ef8  40170054  /system/lib/libc.so
I DEBUG   :          413d6efc  4014864c  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+176)
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near r0:
I DEBUG   :     41dab690 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41dab6a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000006  ................
I DEBUG   :     41dab6b0 00000001 00000000 00000001 00002710  .............'..
I DEBUG   :     41dab6c0 00000007 00000000 000000f1 00000001  ................
I DEBUG   :     41dab6d0 00000000 000007b1 30303031 00303030  ........1000000.
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near r4:
I DEBUG   :     413d593c 00000001 ffffffff 00000001 ffffffff  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d594c 00000001 ffffffff 00000001 00000004  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d595c 00000001 413d5ac4 00000000 00002710  .....Z=A.....'..
I DEBUG   :     413d596c 00000007 00000000 000000f2 00000001  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d597c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near r6:
I DEBUG   :     41d803c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d803d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000007  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d803e8 0000000b 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d803f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d80408 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000004  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near r7:
I DEBUG   :     413d593c 00000001 ffffffff 00000001 ffffffff  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d594c 00000001 ffffffff 00000001 00000004  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d595c 00000001 413d5ac4 00000000 00002710  .....Z=A.....'..
I DEBUG   :     413d596c 00000007 00000000 000000f2 00000001  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d597c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near r8:
I DEBUG   :     413d58e8 00000000 41d803e8 ffffffff ffffffff  .......A........
I DEBUG   :     413d58f8 00000007 40186acc ffffffff ffffffff  .....j.@........
I DEBUG   :     413d5908 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d5918 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d5928 0000000b 00000002 00000008 00010003  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near r9:
I DEBUG   :     40186aac 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     40186abc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     40186acc e362c3df 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..b.............
I DEBUG   :     40186adc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     40186aec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near sl:
I DEBUG   :     41d803c8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d803d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000007  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d803e8 0000000b 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d803f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d80408 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000004  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near ip:
I DEBUG   :     7fffffe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I DEBUG   :     7ffffff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I DEBUG   :     80000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I DEBUG   :     80000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I DEBUG   :     80000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory near sp:
I DEBUG   :     413d57f0 0000000b 41d803e8 413d595c 413d5908  .......A\Y=A.Y=A
I DEBUG   :     413d5800 40186acc 41d803e8 df0027ad 00000000  .j.@...A.'......
I DEBUG   :     413d5810 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     413d5820 00000001 413d595c 40186acc 401a3477  ....\Y=A.j.@w4.@
I DEBUG   :     413d5830 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : code around pc:
I DEBUG   :     401a3130 2a00316c f103d042 605a0224 316cf8d6  l1.*B...$.Z`..l1
I DEBUG   :     401a3140 f506e036 f8de3e9c b1100168 4b2d492c  6....>..h...,I-K
I DEBUG   :     401a3150 88606019 369cf506 f7ef3024 f8c6fd9b  .``....6$0......
I DEBUG   :     401a3160 b9c00168 20064e31 447e4a31 447a4b31  h...1N. 1J~D1KzD
I DEBUG   :     401a3170 4631447b eb0af7ef 49206920 f7ef4622  {D1F.... i I"F..
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : code around lr:
I DEBUG   :     41d93bc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 04380780  ..............8.
I DEBUG   :     41d93bd8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d93be8 00000000 00000002 001fa400 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d93bf8 000fd200 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   :     41d93c08 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
I DEBUG   : 
I DEBUG   : memory map around fault addr c0debadd:
I DEBUG   :     beee1000-bef02000 [stack]
I DEBUG   :     (no map for address)
I DEBUG   :     ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
E mm-camera: 
E mm-camera: Camera Daemon starting
E mm-camera: qcamsvr_start: old_mode = 3f
```

The code of the simplest test for running a camera in the service every 5 minute, taking 200 preview frames, and does a notification if it cannot get the camera.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public class DummyService extends Service implements PreviewCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    // might need a way to determine who is telling us what to do
    public static final String BUNDLE_TAG_SOURCE    = "source";
    public static final String SOURCE_ALARM_MANAGER = "AlarmManager";
    public static final int ALARM_PERIOD_IN_MINUTES = 1;    
    public static final int ALARM_PERIOD_IN_MSEC = ALARM_PERIOD_IN_MINUTES*60*1000;

    final int NumberOfFrames = 200;
    int framesLeft = NumberOfFrames;    
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0; 
    Camera camera;
    final int AlarmMinutes = 5;
    int alarmMinutesLeft = 0;
    boolean isProcessing = false;

    // gets invoked once - gets invoked via StartServiceBroadcastReceiver when the phone is started
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {   
        Log("DummyService: onCreate");

        setupAlarmManager();

           // Start foreground service to avoid unexpected kill
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Background Video Recorder")
            .setContentText("")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();
        startForeground(1234, notification);

    }

    synchronized void setProcessing(boolean processing)
    {
        isProcessing = processing;
    }

    synchronized boolean isProcessing()
    {
        return isProcessing;
    }

    // gets invoked each time startService is called or via alarm manage
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {   
        if(!isProcessing() && (alarmMinutesLeft <= 0))
        {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

            // on a G-slate tablet seems to always be visible; putting in upper left corner
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1, -2000, -2000, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
            surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
            surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

            // crashed here (unable to add window - permission denied for this windows type), fixed with <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
            wm.addView(surfaceView, params);

            SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

            // going to add a callback to the surface holder
            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

            // this starts the process of getting the camera
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

            // deprecated but we'll leave it
            surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }
        else
        {
            Log("Alarm Minutes Left: " + alarmMinutesLeft); 
            alarmMinutesLeft--;
        }

        return START_STICKY;            // run until it is explicitly stopped
    }


    // always going to fire alarms
    private void setupAlarmManager()
    {
        Log("setupAlarmManager() ");                
        // define an intent to be fired periodically
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DummyService.class);
        intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_TAG_SOURCE, SOURCE_ALARM_MANAGER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); // flag ensures the bundle can be received

        // the following causes onStartCommand to be invoked every 60 seconds 
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating (AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), ALARM_PERIOD_IN_MSEC, pendingIntent);         
    }


    // bind related
    public final IBinder binder = new DummyServiceBinder();


    public class DummyServiceBinder extends Binder 
    {
        public DummyService getService() 
        {
            return DummyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return binder;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void notifyUser()
    {
        Notification.Builder mBuilder =
                new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("Camera Locked")               
                .setContentText("Camera Locked")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)               
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(999, mBuilder.build());       
    }

    public static void Log(String info)
    {
        android.util.Log.i("Dummy", info);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {
        if(framesLeft > 0)
        {
            int expectedBytes = width * height * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21) / 8;
            camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[expectedBytes]);
            if(framesLeft % 100 == 0)
            {
                Log("FramesLeft: " + framesLeft);
            }
            framesLeft--;           
        }
        else
        {
            Log("Frames Completed");

            if(camera != null)
            {
                camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);              
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
            alarmMinutesLeft = AlarmMinutes;
            setProcessing(false);
            framesLeft = 200;
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        Log("surfaceCreated");      
        try
        {
            camera = Camera.open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            notifyUser();
            camera = null;
            alarmMinutesLeft = AlarmMinutes; 
            setProcessing(false);           
            Log("Exception while opening camera:  " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        if(camera != null)
        {
            try
            {
                setProcessing(true);

                // set up preview
                camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

                //get highest preview resolution
                List<Camera.Size> unsortedSizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

                class SizeCompare implements Comparator<Camera.Size> {
                    public int compare(Camera.Size lhs, Camera.Size rhs) {
                        if (lhs.width < rhs.width) return 1;
                        if (lhs.width > rhs.width) return -1;
                        if (lhs.height < rhs.height) return 1;
                        if (lhs.height > rhs.height) return -1;
                        return 0;
                    }
                };

                SizeCompare s = new SizeCompare();
                TreeSet<Camera.Size> sortedResolutions = new TreeSet<Camera.Size>(s);
                sortedResolutions.addAll(unsortedSizes);

                ArrayList<Camera.Size> mPreviewSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>(sortedResolutions);                

                width = mPreviewSizes.get(0).width;
                height = mPreviewSizes.get(0).height;

                Log("Using preview size of " + width + "x" + height);

                p.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
                p.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                camera.setParameters(p);

                camera.startPreview();

                int expectedBytes = width * height * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21) / 8;

                camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[expectedBytes]);

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        Log("surfaceChanged");  

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        Log("surfaceDestroyed");    

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried finding the underlying reason of the error using the NDK stack tool (http://yssays.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/android-ndk-stack-tool/)? This will usually tell you something more intelligible about the fault.

Answer (score 0):

turn on screen for 0.5 sec - when service use camera with screen off.
i try many android phone.
it always work.
but i dont know why@@?

if use camera with screen off without turn on screen 0.5 sec
camera always lock @O@!